# Database Design SQL - Inserted Checkbox values during edit

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm developing an application and have a question regarding the database design. I have a table called 'consultant', a table 'branch' and a table that has a collection of the consultant_id and the selected branch_id.

What happens is that during inserting a new consultant all branch names are shown in checkboxes. The user fills information about the consultant and selects certain checkboxes. Information about consultant is inserted in the consultant table and the selected branches are inserted in a table consultant_branch that includes id of consultant and id of branch. Is this database design right?

Secondly I do understand that I would insert the selected branches into consultant_branch table during saving. But, during edit how would i do that? Delete all consultant ids and save again the selected branches into the consultant_branch table? Here the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consultant` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `street` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `plz` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `branch` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consultant_branch` (
 `consultant_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `branch_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 KEY `consultant_id` (`consultant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `consultant_branch` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_bbb` FOREIGN KEY (`consultant_id`) REFERENCES `consultant` (`id`)    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: What's the Primary Key of `consultant_branch`? (I guess it's the combination of the two columns but why ir's missing?)

Comment: the primary key is not needed - i think - because the table may have multiple same entries of the consultant_id. What i would like to ensure is whether the approach is fine and what i would do when a user edits the selected branches of a consultant

Comment: I would have a `PRIMARY KEY` of `(consultant_id, branch_id)`, the `FOREIGN KEY` (that you already have and another `FOREIGN KEY branch_id REFERENCES branch (branch_id)`.

Comment: deleting all branches for the consultant then reinsert is the easiest to implement. you don't have to worry too much about foreign keys because you'll only be deleting from the consultant_branch table.  you should be mindful when deleting from the consultant table.

Comment: @samyi: Yes, but he later adds (or plans to add) other tables that reference this junction table, he has to take that into account.

Comment: I think you're talking about using composite key as your foreign key... am I right?

Answer (score 3):

They are two approach. Let's supose `new` is new list of consultant_banch and `old` is the old one:

1. Delete all `old` that not are in `new` then insert all `new` that not are in `old`. This is the most tedious approach for a developer and expensive in database terms but it is **needed if relation table has other attributes** than primary key (both id's) or **is referenced by other tables**.
2. As you say, **replace** `old` by `new` deleting `old` and inserting `new`.

The analyst will take a decision about best algorithm for your case considering both previos points and grow application prospects.

In any case, **don't forget to enclose all operations in a single transaction** to avoid inconsistent database state. InnoDB supports transactions.